# REACT AXIOS not showing nested items

Tags: reactjs, axios

I am trying to read `Midnight` item in the below response
assuming it is `data.timings.Midnight` , but it is not showing in my react.
Is there away iterate through these nested items and show them ?

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
{
   "code": 200,
   "status": "OK",
   "data": [{
       "timings": {
           "s": "03:57",
           "Ss": "05:46",
           "Dh": "12:59",
           "Asr": "16:55",
           "Sun": "20:12",
           "Mag": "20:12",
           "Is": "22:02",
           "DATAIMintested": "03:47",
           "Midnight": "00:59"
       },
       "date": {
           "readable": "24 Apr 2014",
           "timestamp": "1398332113",
           "gregorian": {
               "date": "15-05-2018",
               "format": "DD-MM-YYYY",
               "day": "15",
               "weekday": {
                   "en": "Tuesday"
               },
               "month": {
                   "number": 5,
                   "en": "May",
               },
               "year": "2018",
               "designation": {
                   "abbreviated": "AD",
                   "expanded": "Domini",
               },
```

Comment: data is an *array*, it doesn't have a timings property (although it contains objects that do).

Answer (score 0):

You are getting an array in the response. I assume you want to access the zeroeth element in the array. You can do it as below

```
Axios.get('<your url>')
.then(res => {
  const responseData = res.data;
  if(responseData && responseData.length > 0){
    const midnight = responseData[0].timings.Midnight;
    ...
     ...
  }
})
.catch(...)
```

Comment: Thank you 
shouldnt i use map() ?
also what if i need access more than one item ? like gregorian date and weekday en ?

Comment: can't i just use map() ? to iterate through ? also how do i render() data back to be displayed ?

Comment: `map` will give you an array. Once you have extracted the value from the json you can display it in the UI

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing it is an array of objects, try to access the array's elements using  indexes.Something like

```
axios.get(url).then(resp => {
    console.log(resp.data[0].timings.Midnight);
});
```